# Irregular build errors in TFS 2015 (missing assembly)

Tags: tfs, build

We have set up TFS (2015) with a build server and have several solutions that are built (some manually, others automatically).

Sometimes a build will inexplicably fail, with a lot of errors stating that assemblies are missing, like so:

```
The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

To fix it I simply need to queue the build again. No edits, no check-ins, just "queue new build", and it builds successfully.

It can happen on manual builds, on automatic builds, on a single build or when building multiple solutions. I can't see any recognizable pattern to why this happens. I don't think it is a nuget issue, because we see different errors when the build server fails at downloading nuget packages (also, is nuget even used for downloading System.Runtime? I assume that library is readily available on the server?)

As I said, it is easy to fix this, but we're using continous integration and automatic deployment (Octopus) to streamline our release cycle, and these "fake" errors are damn annoying when the build error buzzer starts ringing.

Comment: Are you using the new web-based build system or the older XAML build system?

Comment: Are you using multiple buildservers ?

Comment: So knowing nothing about your build script/solutions etc this is a wild guess but since this is random it's quite possible. Have you enabled MSBUILD parallel compilation? If yes, have you defined all the project dependency properly within the solution file? If the parallel build is enabled (MSBUILD /m or /maxcpucount switch) and if you havent defined the dependencies properly there is a chance that a dependent project is getting built earlier than one of it's dependencies.

Comment: @Isaiah4110 I can't see any options for parallel builds in the UI, and there's no switches for cpucount or parallelism in the build arguments, so I have to assume that we're not doing anything in parallel unless that is on by default

We're using the web based build system and we have multiple build servers

Comment: Can you share your build steps? At which step will the error show up?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT powershell-script that sets the assembly version number, then build solution. It fails as soon as it starts parsing classes, telling me that libraries like System.Runtime and System.Globalization aren't referenced.

Comment: Do you have Nuget Restore step?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT Yes, it that step doesn't fail. When it does (only happened a couple of times the last year), whether it's network issues or something else, we get a completely different error message.
I will try to see if the build servers match up, but I can't find any logs that describe which agent was used for a specific build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, as might be expected, human error. All available build agents were added to the pool for this particular solution, and one of those agents didn't have .Net Framework 4.5.2 installed.
The agent was removed from the pool, and if the feedback I got from the sysadmins is correct then the errors should stop occurring now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set 'MSBuild Arguments' to `/m:1` to force MSBuild to use a single process for all projects, to see whether it is helpful.